# Copying table from Server A to server B

Tags: mysql, bash, shell

We have a script which is working perfectly, we use it to copy a huge database from server A to server B. Now I want to copy just a table from server A to server B having the table name as a variable so the script should only ask for the table name and copy the table from A to B.
This is the script I have made, I must confess I am not very experienced in shell scripting.

```
#!/bin/sh

#Run on Server A
TABLENAME=$1

echo $TABLENAME

_now=$(date +"%A %d-%m-%Y "at" %T")

#Copy table $TABLENAME  from server A to server B
#Dump table into /directory server A
mysqldump -u admin -p'*****' database_name $TABLENAME >             /directory/$TABLENAME.sql
# Copie table to server B
scp /directory/$TABLENAME.sql root@server_b.domain.com:/directory/
# Replace table in database on server B
ssh root@server_b.domain.com "mysql -f -u admin -p'******' database_name -e     'source /directory/$TABLENAME.sql'"  
#Remove file on server B
ssh root@server_b.domain.com "rm /directory/$TABLENAME.sql"
#Remove file on A
rm /directory/$TABLENAME.sql
```

this is the error i get:

```
.sql                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
./script_file_name: line 19: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
./script_file_name: line 22: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry to have bothered you, this is the solution of my problem:
 1. i had 2 $ in my mysql password which needed to be escaped like 'fds\$fds\$gfds\$' i did not know this before.
 2. The script will not ask for a table name but the table name must be typed as a parameter after the run command like this: 
    ./filename table_name

Answer (score 1):

You are missing quotes (",') as part of the command.

```
ssh root@server_b.domain.com "mysql -f -u admin -p'******' database_name -e     'source /directory/$TABLENAME'"
```

Comment: i have added quote, now it tries  to copy the all database and does not ask for table name

Answer (score 1):

Try this as your combined ssh and mysql statement:

```
ssh root@server_b.domain.com "mysql -h localhost -u admin -p'******' database_name -e 'source /directory/$TABLENAME'"
```

- Added -h and the database host.
- Removed the -f switch.

Let me know how it went.

Comment: hi Pcs txs for your suggestion, this does not help, the mysql  statement is ok as we use it also for other scripts which work just fine. The scrip should first ask for the tablename but it does not

Comment: Hi @papacico, if you want to read something from the commandline (after the script is started), use the read shell builtin. For instance: "read TABLENAME." .

Comment: Hi @Pdc, txs for your suggestion i have tried but probably i do something wrong as i don't know this 'read' . Could you pls write just a line of code as an example? Thank you

Comment: Sure @papacio, try this in a Bash file `read input` and `echo $input`. This will in effect read one line (ended with carriage return, line break), store the data in $input and write the contents of the variable on screen. For more info, try `man read` to find out about reading from file descriptors (such as stdin in this case).

Answer (score 1):

Just to complete my input with the following solution that worked fine for me.

Except some changed directory names and , this is the same principle and problem solved.

Hope this is useful.

```
#!/bin/sh

        # Copy table $TABLENAME (passed as argument)
        # from server A to server B.

# Run on Server A
TABLENAME=$1
echo $TABLENAME

# Dump table into /root/bash on server A.
mysqldump -h localhost -u root -p'***' tablename $TABLENAME > /root/bash/$TABLENAME.sql

# Copy table to server B.
scp /root/bash/$TABLENAME.sql root@<ip address>:/root/bash/$TABLENAME.sql2

# Replace table in database on server B
ssh root@<ip address> "mysql -f -u root -p'***' tablename -e 'source /root/bash/$TABLENAME.sql2'" 

# Remove file on server B.
ssh root@<ip address> "rm /root/bash/$TABLENAME.sql2"

# Remove file on A
rm /root/bash/$TABLENAME.sql
```